# Sorting a vector by the number of time each value occurs

Tags: matlab, sorting

We have the following case:

```
    Q = [idxcell{:,1}];     
    Sort = sort(Q,'descend')                                                                                                                       
    Sort =
          Columns 1 through 13
            23    23    22    22    20    19    18    18    18    18    17    17    17
          Columns 14 through 26
            15    15    14    14    13    13    13    12    12    12    11    10     9
          Columns 27 through 39
             9     9     8     8     8     8     8     7     7     7     7     7     7
          Columns 40 through 52
             7     6     6     6     5     4     4     3     3     3     3     2     2
          Columns 53 through 64
             2     2     2     2     2     2     2     1     1     1     1     1
```

How can we sort matrix Sort according to how many times its values are repeated?

Awaiting result should be:

```
repeatedSort =  2(9) 7(7) 1(5) 8(5) 3(4) 18(4) 6(3) 9(3) 12(3) 13(3) 17(3) 4(2) 14(2) 15(2) 22(2) 23(2) 5(1) 10(1) 11(1) 19(1) 20(1)
      or 
repeatedSort = 2 7 1 8 3 18 6 9 12 13 17 4 14 15 22 23 5 10 11 19 20
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are the values limited in range like from 0 to 1000, because if so you could do a bucket sort on them.

Comment: @datdo In this scenario its limited to 100 yes.

Comment: woops. I misread the question.  Bucket sort is not the way to go, it would just return the same vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
d      = randi(10,1,30); %Some fake data
n      = histc(d,1:10);
[y,ii] = sort(n,'descend');

disp(ii) % ii is now sorted according to frequency
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [TABULATE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html) function from the Statistics Toolbox, then call [SORTROWS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) to sort by the frequency.

Example:

```
x = randi(10, [20 1]);    %# random values
t = tabulate(x);          %# unique values and counts
t = t(find(t(:,2)),1:2);  %# get rid of entries with zero count
t = sortrows(t, -2)       %# sort according to frequency
```

the result, where first column are the unique values, second is their count:

```
t =
     2     4     %# value 2 appeared four times
     5     4     %# etc...
     1     3
     8     3
     7     2
     9     2
     4     1
     6     1
```

Comment: Thank you this solution is also very effective @Amro